# SQL Joining 2 tables with a consideration of a hidden field/flag

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables in my DB, Im trying to join using codeignighter, the tables are `categories_has_products` with the `products` table so that I can get a list of products that are `visible`.

If `visible` == 0, then I do not want to get these products.

The `category` table is somewhat irrelevant to this as I already know the category ID to collect data for, however I thought Id better include the the design/table just for ref.

**My Attempts**

I have attempted this myself however a little rusty with SQL

`$this->db->join('categories_has_products', 'categories_has_products.product_id = products.id', 'left')
        ->where('visible',1)->get('products');`

**Products**

```
id | name | visible 
---+------+--------
1  | abc  | 1
2  | def  | 1
3  | ghi  | 0
4  | jkl  | 1
5  | mno  | 1
```

**Categories_has_Products**

```
id | category_id | product_id| 
---+--------+
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 3
3  | 1      | 4
```

**Categories**

```
id | name   | 
---+--------+
1  | fruit  | 
1  | drinks |
```

**Expected Results**

```
id | name | visible 
---+------+---------
1  | abc  | 1
4  | jkl  | 1
```

Comment: You should post your update (your solution) as an answer rather than an edit to your question. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the result set you want, you shouldn't be using a LEFT join. Something like this should work (untested, naturally)

```
    $this->db->select('products.*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('categories_has_products', 'categories_has_products.product_id = products.id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->where('products.visible !=', 0);
```